# create a list of of results of a function, which also includes which inputs led to result if certain threshhold is met

Tags: r

I'm using the following code

```
function(x,y) { RecordLinkage::levenshteinSim(x,y) }
```

to calculate the percent similarity between 2 inputs.

So far I decided to store the results in a matrix

```
matrix=outer(matext_vec,matext_, FUN=myfun)
```

But because my vector is so long the matrix gets too big in regards to memory.

Could I put in a threshhold saying, that only if the value is bigger than e.g. 0.9 a list should be created putting in the value as well as the inputs, that led to the value.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the output is too big for your memory, how will augmenting the output with the input help?

Comment: Sorry I must've been pretty phased out. I meant to mention the fact, that I wanted to use a threshhold so that a list contains only the values that met the threshhold thus reducing the amount of entries in comparison to a matrix

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: By working column by column you don't need to hold the entire matrix in memory at once.

Comment: how would I do that ?

Comment: As a preliminary step, you could write a function `f(x,v,t)` which returns all elements `y` in the vector `v` where the similarity between `x` and `y` exceeds the threshold `t`. Once that works, fix `v` to be `matext_` and let `x` vary over `matext_vec`. If you follow the recommendation of @Sotos and give a reproducible example I could try to flesh this out some more.